# Lopez de Prado Advances in Financial Machine Learning- entropy for adverse selection

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, finance-mathematics, market-microstructure, machine-learning, limit-order-book

In chapter 18: Entropy Features, Lopez de Prado discusses how entropy can be used to estimate adverse selection. He suggests a method where order imbalance is mapped to quantiles and entropy is calculated for this time series, he then says we can estimate a distribution F(H(X)), but H(X) is a single value calculated across the time series, so how can we find a distribution for this, then proceed to calculate values of F(H(Xt)) for each time point (what even is the notion of F(H(Xt)) when Xt is a single value, is the author defining Xt=X{t’<=t}, if so this isn’t very clear, and we certainly wouldn’t be able to calculate the entropy for the first few values in the time series as there would be too few points)

Comment: Sounds like the author hasn't thought things through very well yet.